# Cmd instantly closes

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, sysinternals

So my cmd instantly closes, I tried following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373137/cmd-exe-closes-immediately-after-calling-win7-64 this kind of solves the problem but it introduces a new one, when my pc starts, windows explorer doesn't start (and probably some other processes). I can manually run the explorer process from task manager every time I start windows but that's annoying.

What I currently have in that registry is

```
@mode 20,5 & tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq SoundMixer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "SoundMixer.exe">NUL && exit & if exist "C:\Users\Dddsasul\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoundMixer\SoundMixer.exe" ( start /MIN "" "C:\Users\Dddsasul\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoundMixer\SoundMixer.exe" & tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "explorer.exe">NUL && exit & explorer.exe & exit ) else ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "explorer.exe">NUL && exit & explorer.exe & exit )
```

I was wondering what can I do to fix this (Keep in mind that I am an inexperienced user, I do not understand what's inside that registry, it was already there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### So my `cmd` instantly closes.

That is because you have an `Autoruns` key in there which is starting `explorer` and then `exit`ing.

That key seems to be there because something else is broken and `explorer` is not starting when you log on.

Note that the key is not required for normal operation of Windows.

You need to fix explorer first and then remove the `Autoruns` key.

To fix `explorer`:

- Run `regedt32`
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`.
- On the right side, there should be a value called `Shell`.
- In the right hand side pane, make sure that the default string value of `Shell` is `explorer.exe`.
- Save any changes
- Log off and log on again.

Source [Windows explorer.exe does not start or open at startup](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-explorer-exe-does-not-start)

Comment: I don't have `Shell` there :(